# How to generate token with bank account in stripe?

Tags: android, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I integrated stripe in my android project. Now, I am generating token with card in stripe. That is working fine. But, I want to generate token with Bank Account. I searched in StackOverflow referred some of links. But, it doesn't worked for me. Is there is any way to generate stripe token with bank account in android?

The following code I used. But, it not worked.

```
        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_...";

        Map<String, Object> tokenParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> bank_accountParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        bank_accountParams.put("country", "US");
        bank_accountParams.put("currency", "usd");
        bank_accountParams.put("account_holder_name", "Jane Austen");
        bank_accountParams.put("account_holder_type", "individual");
        bank_accountParams.put("routing_number", "11000000");
        bank_accountParams.put("account_number", "000123456789");
        tokenParams.put("bank_account", bank_accountParams);

        try {
            Token s = Token.create(tokenParams);
            Log.d("Token",s.getId());
            tokens = s.getId();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            showAlertMessage("",e.getMessage());
        } catch (CardException e) {
            showAlertMessage("",e.getMessage());
        } catch (APIException e) {
            showAlertMessage("",e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
            showAlertMessage("", e.getMessage());
        } catch (APIConnectionException e) {
            showAlertMessage("",e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the new docs you need to add following line to gradle build:

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:4.0.1'
```

check for the latest version at this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android)

Then use the following code snippet:

```
Stripe stripe = new Stripe(this);
stripe.setDefaultPublishableKey("your_publishable_key");
BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount("accountNumber","countryCode","currency","routingNumber");
stripe.createBankAccountToken(bankAccount, new TokenCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Exception error) {
        Log.e("Stripe Error",error.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(com.stripe.android.model.Token token) {
        Log.e("Bank Token", token.getId());
    }
});
```

This should work like charm.

Comment: I know this is old post, but still anyone know how get supported country, currency, routing number from any api or does stripe have api for that?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake in my code. That is `Token.create(tokenParams);` should be handled with in `AysncTask`. Because it deals with network. After gone through [their git repository](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/Token.java) I came to know. So, I handled that create token part in async task. The code I have changed is below:

```
int SDK_INT = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        final String[] tokens = {"new"};
        Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_0wgmvQOVjIpspIgKsoW7wtTp";
        final Map<String, Object> tokenParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Map<String, Object> bank_accountParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        bank_accountParams.put("country", "US");
        bank_accountParams.put("currency", "usd");
        bank_accountParams.put("account_holder_name", "Jayden Moore");
        bank_accountParams.put("account_holder_type", "individual");
        bank_accountParams.put("routing_number", "110000000");
        bank_accountParams.put("account_number", "000123456789");
        tokenParams.put("bank_account", bank_accountParams);
        final Token[] responseToken = {null};

        if (SDK_INT > 8)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            //your codes here
            com.stripe.Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_0wgmvQOVjIpspIgKsoW7wtTp";
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Token>() {
                String errorMsg = null;

                @Override
                protected Token doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        return Token.create(tokenParams);
                    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    } catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    } catch (APIConnectionException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    } catch (CardException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    } catch (APIException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(Token result) {
                    if (errorMsg == null) {
//                      success
                    } else {
//                        handleError(errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }.execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by changing this line

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+
```

into this line

```
compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:1.1.1'
```

in my app.gradle file.
This might change for future releases.